# How to Fix "Invalid back stack entry on the NavHostFragment's back stack"?

Tags: android

> ERROR : Invalid back stack entry on the NavHostFragment's back stack - use getChildFragmentManager() if you need to do custom FragmentTransactions from within Fragments created via your navigation graph
>
> Here is my Fragment Home :

```
gallery= root.findViewById(R.id.gallery);

    gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "GAL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new GalleryFragment(), "GalleryFragmentTag");
            getActivity().setTitle("your title");
            ft.commit();
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
        }
    });
    return root;
```

> Here is nav_host_fragment:

```
   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

> Here is GalleryFragment.java:

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    gallery_recycler_view= root.findViewById(R.id.gallery_recycler_view);

    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pd.setMessage("Loading");
    pd.show();

    gallery_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
    final GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
    gallery_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager); // set LayoutManager to RecyclerView
    galleryModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    DatabaseReference dbProducts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("OImages");
    Log.e("path1",dbProducts.toString());

    dbProducts.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {


                for (DataSnapshot productSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    GalleryModel p = productSnapshot.getValue(GalleryModel.class);
                    galleryModelList.add(p);
                }

                adapter = new GalleryAdapter(getActivity(), galleryModelList);


                Collections.reverse(galleryModelList);
                gallery_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);

               // lovelyProgressDialog.dismiss();
                pd.dismiss();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

Comment: have you tried getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager()?

Comment: Is your `R.id.nav_host_fragment` is FrameLayout or Fragment Tag in XML?

Comment: yes @MasterZzzing i tried that, now it crashes again !

Comment: this is nav_host_fragment : @MuhammadFarhan

Comment: <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

Comment: @Zed Oh you're using Navigation Components. Did you follow these Step
1- Adding GalleryFragment to the Navigation Graph.
2- Connecting Fragments in the Graph with Actions.
3- Then Call Navigation Controller and Navigate to GalleryFragment Fragment.

Comment: @Zed Checking if you were able to figure out the solution. I am getting these errors in Crash reports of Dynatrace for the app.